# Why is JSP not mapped in web.xml while servlet does

Tags: jsp, servlets, web.xml

We know servlet and JSP are same from back doors. 
JSP is also servlet, so when JSP executed, it first converted into servlet then servlet execution follows.

My question is, if servlet and JSP are same then why we map servlet in `web.xml` deployment descriptor file, but we don't map JSP?

Answer (score 5):

It's already mapped in server's own `web.xml` which get applied on all webapps. So you don't need to explicitly register it in all your webapps.

In case of e.g. Tomcat, you can find the below JSP servlet related entries in the `/conf/web.xml` file of the Tomcat installation (below line numbers match Tomcat 8.0.26).

```xml
245    <servlet>
255        <servlet-name>jsp</servlet-name>
256        <servlet-class>org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet</servlet-class>
257        <init-param>
258            <param-name>fork</param-name>
259            <param-value>false</param-value>
260        </init-param>
261        <init-param>
262            <param-name>xpoweredBy</param-name>
263            <param-value>false</param-value>
264        </init-param>
265        <load-on-startup>3</load-on-startup>
266    </servlet>
```

```xml
381    <servlet-mapping>
382        <servlet-name>jsp</servlet-name>
383        <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
384        <url-pattern>*.jspx</url-pattern>
385    </servlet-mapping>
```

You see, any request which matches the URL pattern `*.jsp` or `*.jspx` will invoke the server's own `JspServlet` which will then do all the JSP works.

Tomcat has no knowledge about your "custom" servlets, so you won't find your "custom" servlets in there and you'd need to map them in webapp's own `web.xml` yourself.