# Is there a way to get syntax highlighting in Eclipse inside JSF <h:outputScript> tags?

Tags: eclipse, jsf

Well, title says it all, I want syntax highlighting inside `<h:outputScript>` tags, for example:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

  <ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
      xmlns:t="http://myfaces.apache.org/tomahawk">

      <h:panelGroup id="foo">
          blah
      </h:panelGroup>

      <h:outputScript>

        //please highlighting here
        var iousGoogleSearchesLaterIfearThereIsNoSuch = function(but, I, do, want, so) {
           if(youKnow(something)) {
             please(but);
           }
           for (I, do, so, want ;'';);
           return "the favor" && share;
        };

      </h:outputScript>

  </ui:composition>
```

Any tips/tools or ideas? Thanks

Comment: It's more efficient and better practice to put JS code in a JS file.

Comment: @BalusC definitely agreed, and that's what I do like 99% of the cases, but sometimes not an option

Comment: If it's solely the EL evaluation, this may be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/q/34156641 As to the concrete problem, what if you just use `<script>`? The additional benefits of `<h:outputScript>` aren't exactly used in this specific construct.

Comment: @BalusC whoa that `<script>` works! Thanks, good tip, what would be the actual benefits of inline JS in an `<h:outputScript>` though?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given that you don't really take advantage of `<h:outputScript>` component (especially relocation by `target="head|body"` attribute and being able to grab and manipulate it via the component tree), simply use plain HTML `<script>` instead.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    ...
</script>
```

It would be better if you switch to HTML5 doctype, then you don't need to specify `type` attribute too.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
...
<script>
    ...
</script>
```

Nonetheless, putting JS code in its own JS file is more efficient (browser has opportunity to cache it, so overall performance is better) and is considered best practice as to separation of concerns.

#### See also:

- [Is it possible to use JSF+Facelets with HTML 4/5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2935759/is-it-possible-to-use-jsffacelets-with-html-4-5)
- [Do HTML5 Script tag need type="javascript"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14323376/do-html5-script-tag-need-type-javascript/)

Comment: Great answer! Thank you. Could you possibly elaborate on or link to a resource detailing the benefits of `<h:outputScript>` over `<script>`?

Comment: This? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8367421 and this http://showcase.omnifaces.org/resourcehandlers/CombinedResourceHandler